# How do I manipulate a property using an NSString variable?

Tags: objective-c

It seems like I need key value coding. I have a bunch of bluetooth beacons, and when I get a signal from one I need to do something with a property. If the beacon is called Beacon5, then the property is called Beacon5path. I want to make

```
_Beacon5path.hidden = true
```

So I have a variable

```
NSString* myBeacon = @"Beacon5path"
```

And I can do

```
id value = [self valueForKey:myBeacon];
```

How do I then manipulate this?

I tried

```
value.hidden = true;
```

or
    _value.hidden = true;

But those don't do anything.

Comment: Can you show the result of `NSLog(@"Object for Beacon5path: %@", value);` so it's obvious what kind of thing you're trying to modify?

Comment: Wouldn't an array of beacons or a dictionary with the keys as the beacon names be a more straightforward approach than KVC?

Comment: The NSlog shows: Object for Beacon5path: <UIView: 0x1567f140; frame = (152 213; 32 60); alpha = 0.4; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x15693d50>>

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a dictionary, but if I used a dictionary, how do you then mess with the property if it's in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a `UIView` that you want to hide, you can either test that it's the right kind of class and then cast it as a `UIView` to keep the compiler happy or you can take a more general approach and check whether it's anything you can hide, such as:

```
if ([value respondsToSelector:@selector(setHidden:)]) {
    [value setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on this? Are you saying that I still use id value = [self valueForKey:myBeacon];, and then use your code somehow?

Comment: Yes.  Try it.  The other option would be to test `value` using `isKindOfClass` and then cast it to a `(UIView *)` if that was true.